# How the get refs antd componement Select value of antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, antd

I try use last version of antd(3.10.0) and react(16.5.2).

I use the new way of ref according to https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```
this.myRef = React.createRef();
```

when it rend，should like:

```
rend(){
                    <Select style={{ width: 200 }} ref={this.myRef}>
                    {Object.entries(this.state.catedict)
                        .map(en => <Option key={en[0]}>{en[1]}</Option>)}
                </Select>
}
```

But when I want to get the value of Input or Select

I try to:

```
console.log(this.myRef.current.value);
```

But only get wrong result.

I find even:

```
console.log(this.myRef.current);
```

the result is:

```
t {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, saveSelect: ƒ, …}
context: {}
props: {style: {…}, children: Array(2), prefixCls: "ant-select", showSearch: false, transitionName: "slide-up", …}
rcSelect: t {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, onInputChange: ƒ, …}
refs: {}
renderSelect: ƒ (n)
saveSelect: ƒ (n)
state: null
updater: {isMounted: ƒ, enqueueSetState: ƒ, enqueueReplaceState: ƒ, enqueueForceUpdate: ƒ}
_reactInternalFiber: Na {tag: 2, key: null, type: ƒ, stateNode: t, return: Na, …}
__proto__: v
```

I want give the value of Select. How should I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

save value of `Select` on every change! and use it when you want.

```
<Select style={{ width: 200 }} onChange={(value)=>{
    this.selectValue = value;
}}>
```

and use it in other place:

```
console.log('Select Value', this.selectValue)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get it by the ref,the antd select is hoc of rc-select,if you want to get the value,you still get it by ref.rcSelect

```
`the react dom`
<Select ref={r => this.ctryListRef = r} />

`the js code`
console.log(this.ctryListRef.rcSelect.state.value)
```

by the rcSelect.state.value, you can get the value.

In addition, you can get antd textArea value, it's just another hoc~